# Django channels-redis WS

Tags: python, django, websocket, redis

I have a problem with Redis WebSocket connection.
I am using a server that prefers a unixsocket configuration. [REDIS CONF FOR MY SERVER](https://wiki.mydevil.net/Redis)

My files and sample template look like this:

#### settings.py

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'public_python.asgi.application'


CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [(("unix:///home/Login/domains/domain.pl/redis.sock", 8560), {"password": "my_pass"})],
        },
    },
}
```

#### asgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
import TableSG.urls  # importuj swoje urlpatterns dla WebSocket z urls.py

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'public_python.settings')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": get_asgi_application(),
    "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            TableSG.urls.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

#### views.py

```
def items_view(request):
    return render(request, 'TableSG/item.html')

class ItemConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        await self.accept()

        items = await self.get_items()
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps(items))

    @database_sync_to_async
    def get_items(self):
        items = SklepModel.objects.all().values()
        return list(items)
```

#### urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

app_name = 'TableSG'

urlpatterns = [
    # other urls
    path('items/', views.items_view, name='items'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    path('ws/items/', views.ItemConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

#### template item.html

```
{% extends "BaseSG/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
    <ul id="items">

    </ul>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = new WebSocket('wss://' + window.location.host + '/ws/items/');

        socket.onmessage = function(e) {
            var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
            var items = $('#items');
            items.empty();

            data.forEach(function(item) {
                items.append('<li>' + item.temat + ': ' + item.opis + '</li>');
            });
        };

        socket.onclose = function(e) {
            console.error('Chat socket closed unexpectedly');
        };
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

I keep getting the error "WebSocket connection to 'wss://domain.pl/ws/items/' failed:"

redis.conf has port, unixsocket, requirepass etc.
I have no more ideas why it doesn't work.
I use django channels and django channels-redis
My Django is 4.1.3